# Powers that change the world

Tags: science-fiction, space, near-future, super-powers

In the world of 2144 where everyone has a gift or “power”, the powers can be as subtle as floating or healing and as dangerous as controlling time or manifesting fire. What gift or power would be suitable for the main character to make an impact or change in a world ravaged by crime and fear and on the brink of war? It can be anything but has to be powerful and very unique. Any ideas?? Plz help

Comment: It's me you have done this question 10 minutes ago?

Comment: It was put on hold. I reposted the question.

Comment: This question is called 'story generation.' You are asking answerers to generate story. This is a Q & A site, that is, you ask a question and you get an answer. For story generation, there is no 'answer', it is just making things  up. Therefore, I am voting to close this question as 'primarily opinion-based'.

Comment: It’s not story generation. It’s not opinion based. I asked a question and I am getting answers. Thanks for the vote anyways.

Comment: you have not clear how this site works. And re posting questions put on hold is not really appreciated.

Comment: (x-men ripoff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This person could have the ability to change anyone he/she sees so that other person can no longer hurt another person, and no longer wants to. The hero's ability could affect people he sees in photos or on video - so a live stream video of a whole area of unrest would allow the hero to change all those people.

Some people would want to avoid this person, or avoid being seen by this person, so they could continue to be evil. But their "foot soldiers" would all be disabled if seen, so the bad leaders' ability to sow discontent would get more and more limited.

Answer (score 2):

To live outside of time.

I mean: to be able to see what happened in the past and what will happen in the future.

You might want to limit this power by allowing to see whatever happened or will happen *where he is looking*, so that he/she has to be in the physical location where fact did/will happen.

Answer (score 1):

**Borrow power.**

Your character does not have his own power, but can borrow the powers of others for a time.  This is not the most original idea since the Xman Rogue has this power, but its potential is really underused for her character who instead is a typical flying she-bruiser.

Borrowing powers allows mix and match which I think is cool as stink.  Also it is reciprocal - as opposed to Rogue who just knocks people out when she borrows from them, those borrowed from get as good as they give.  Whatever powers the character has at that moment, the one borrowed from gets those too.

And they get the viewpoint of the borrower.  The whole reason [Rogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(comics)) changed from villain to hero is that she borrowed from an alien superhero and kept what she borrowed, including the do-gooder personality of the alien (who died in the process).  In addition to powers, your borrower also receives the viewpoints and some of the persona of what he borrows - and can confer the same.

Comment: Ms Marvel is neither an alien nor dead.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile - ah, I see.  She only has alien (Kree) _genes_ and only her absorbed persona was killed.  Details!

Answer (score 1):

Obvious answer springs to mind: LOVE.

The greatest power yet known, it defeats hatred by altering all kinds of hardened mental states. It's unique because it's not a power that has anything to with the physical world. Manifestation of fire is just initiating a chemical combustion reaction. Powers of hatred and violence are rooted in malice and fear. Criminals can only win by intimidating people. Love wins by rising up from the mind and heart of an individual and infecting another person and another and whole communities. Primary world examples certainly abound in great numbers.